# Symfony POST request is passing validation where it should be giving errors

Tags: php, api, symfony

OrderModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto\Request\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class OrderModel
{
    #[Assert\Uuid(message: "Order id must be an unique identifier value.")]
    #[Assert\Positive(message: "Order id must be a positive integer value.")]
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\Positive(message="customerId must be a positive integer value.")
     */
    public int $customerId;

    public array $items;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type("string", message="Order total must be a string float value.")
     * @Assert\Type("float", message="Order total must be a string float value.")
     */
    public string $total;
}
```

OrderType.php

```
<?php

use App\Dto\Request\Model\OrderModel;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('customerId', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('items', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ItemType::class
            ])
            ->add('total', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => OrderModel::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

OrderController.php:

```
#[Route('/order', name:'order_new', methods: 'POST')]
public function create(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request): JsonResponse|Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(\OrderType::class);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
        if(!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()){
            return $this->handleView($this->view($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
        }
    }
}
```

My Post Request:

```
{
  "id": "dsdas",
  "customerId": 1,
  "items": [
      {
          "productId": 1,
          "quantity": 1,
          "unitPrice": "250.25",
          "total": "250.25"
      },
      {
          "productId": 1,
          "quantity": 1,
          "unitPrice": "250.25",
          "total": "250.25"
      }
  ],
  "total": "500.50"
}
```

This request is passing validation and I'm trying to figure out. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the form name in the submitted data as top-level key. You are trying to send this:

```
{
    "id": "dsdas",
    "customerId": 1,
    "total": "500.50"
}
```

And your code ($request->request->get($form->getName())) expects this (if the form name is "order_type")

```
{
    "order_type": {
        "id": "dsdas",
        "customerId": 1,
        "total": "500.50"
    }
}
```

One solution is to create a named form with ... no name :)

```
public function create(
    Request $request,
    FormFactoryInterface $formFactory
) {
    // Create form with no name: setting the first parameter to '' means no name (ideal for API endpoints)
    $form = $formFactory->createNamed('', OrderType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if(
        !$form->isSubmitted() ||
        !$form->isValid()
    ) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The second solution is to add the form name yourself

```
public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse|Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(\OrderType::class);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit([
            // You can also add the key yourself right before submitting
            $form->getName() => $request->request->all(),
        ]);
        if(
            !$form->isSubmitted() ||
            !$form->isValid()
        ){
            return $this->handleView($this->view($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
        }
    }
}
```

A third option but not the best one is that you always send your data WITH the form key to the controller, but I would not go for this option if it an API endpoint. So only if it is a regular form submission and the submitted form fields are all generated with the original form name prefix.

As a last option, you can also catch both data formats coming in. Maybe something like this so you can actually send with or without the key:

```
$finalData = $request->request->get($form->getName()) ?: $request->request->all();
$form->submit([$form->getName() => $finalData]);
```

Comment: I've tried the second solution and it is working great. Thanks. Now I'm getting "This form should not contain extra fields." error. Checking out the incoming data with $request->request->all(); and seems exactly the same with my models. If I add 'allow_extra_fields' => true to OrderType.php configureOptions' $resolver->setDefaults the validator is not working at all. Looking for a solution, I'd be happy if you have any ideas.

Comment: Found the problem. Added 'allow_add' => true after 'entry_type' => ItemType::class in OrderType.php, also added #[Assert\Valid] just before public array $items in OrderModel.php so that Order's items will be validated. Hope this helps someone. Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add

Comment: First you check what the "extra fields" are. It could be a _token or something like that if a form generated by Symfony submitted this data. You could add this to the options: `'allow_extra_fields' => true` or the option `'csrf_protection' => in_array('_token', $theSubmittedFields)` (csrf_protection must be true IF a key with _token gets sent)